# R: Recursively add rows

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rolling-computation, accumulate

The concentration of germs of hands following j surface contacts can be dictated by the following recursive relationship:

```
H[j+1]=H[j]+T[j]*(S[j]-H[j])
```

Where `S` is the surface concentration the hand touches (and is assumed random for ease). `T` is the transfer efficiency for each contact. I would like to calculate the eventual hand concentration (with zero starting concentration).

I have a data frame that has a vector of surface contacts and transfer efficiencies for each surface. I have two groups `a` & `b` and within each group assume I will touch each one sequentially `1:length(df)`:

```
 df <- data.frame(S = runif(10)*100, T = runif(10),g=rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
```

I would like to compute the cumulative sum of `H` by group using `dplyr` where possible.

**a special case:**

If `g = "a"`, the starting value of `H` is `0`.
If `g=="b"` then the starting value of `H` is the last value from when `g=="a"`

Comment: It is not clear what `H` is in your data set. So I think it would be better if you edit your question a little bit.

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked? It's unclear right now how exactly your code will relate to the equation, and what could be going wrong with trying to implement it

Comment: very good question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a similar approach as showed by @AnilGoyal for a generalized case

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(H = accumulate2(S, T* !lead(!duplicated(g), default = FALSE),
          .init = 0, ~ ..1 + ..3 * (..2 - ..1))[-n()])
```

Comment: You guys used dark magic to solve this, while I'm a simple mortal human :)

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness and taking clues from Arun and Onyambu (on a separate question), I am adding baseR answer here too.

```
transform(df, H = Reduce(function(.x, .y) .x + df$T[.y] * (df$S[.y] - .x) * !c(!duplicated(df$g)[-1], 0)[.y],
                         seq(nrow(df)),
                         init = 0,
                         accumulate = TRUE)[-(1 + nrow(df))])

           S         T g        H
1  37.698250 0.8550377 a  0.00000
2   3.843585 0.4722659 a 32.23342
3  33.150788 0.3684791 a 18.82587
4   8.948116 0.8893603 a 24.10430
5  57.061844 0.5452377 a 10.62499
6  49.648827 0.7719067 b 10.62499
7  95.403697 0.5835950 b 40.74775
8  10.598677 0.1220491 b 72.64469
9  91.913365 0.2166443 b 65.07203
10 69.644200 0.2603413 b 70.88705
```

---

**Earlier Answer**
A slight variation of my friend's answer above, I hope that may serve your purpose.  Only assumption I am having is that your data is sorted by groups already and `a` precedes `b` (exactly as shown in sample).  Since you have not given the random seed, I am also taking the same data took by my friend.

- Strategy/hack, I used `0` value of `T` inside `accumulate2` argument so that last value of `H` in group `a` is repeated in first value of group `b`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '           S         T g
1  37.698250 0.8550377 a
2   3.843585 0.4722659 a
3  33.150788 0.3684791 a
4   8.948116 0.8893603 a
5  57.061844 0.5452377 a
6  49.648827 0.7719067 b
7  95.403697 0.5835950 b
8  10.598677 0.1220491 b
9  91.913365 0.2166443 b
10 69.644200 0.2603413 b')

df %>%
  mutate(H = accumulate2(S, replace(T, length(g[g=='a']), 0), .init = 0, ~ ..1 + ..3 * (..2 - ..1))[-(1+n())])


           S         T g        H
1  37.698250 0.8550377 a  0.00000
2   3.843585 0.4722659 a 32.23342
3  33.150788 0.3684791 a 18.82587
4   8.948116 0.8893603 a 24.10430
5  57.061844 0.5452377 a 10.62499
6  49.648827 0.7719067 b 10.62499
7  95.403697 0.5835950 b 40.74775
8  10.598677 0.1220491 b 72.64469
9  91.913365 0.2166443 b 65.07203
10 69.644200 0.2603413 b 70.88705

#check - formula
#H[j+1]=H[j]+T[j]*(S[j]-H[j])
# for j =2
# H[2] = H[1] + T[1] * (S[1] -H[1])

0 + 0.8550377 * (37.698250 - 0)
#> [1] 32.23342

#for j=7 (second row group b)

#H[6] + T[6] * (S[6] - H[6])
10.62499 + 0.7719067 * (49.648827 - 10.62499)
#> [1] 40.74775
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much Anil for introducing accumulate2. I have not seen this before and I think it will now be part of my workflow soon. I would like to accept Akrun's answer because it is the general solution where g could have any length.

Comment: @HCAI, he generalized it so easily whereas it took me a while to figure out how to do it.  His strategy is undoubtedly best here.  :)

Comment: I would like to offer you a bounty when stack allows me to. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @HCAI, edited the earlier answer for a small bug there (previously I was clipping penultimate value and not last value as expected).  Plus I have added a BaseR strategy too to handle cases with multiple inputs in `accumulate/Reduce` family which I have learned from my friends Anoushiravan and Onyambu

Answer (score 3):

Here is another generalized version I would use for this question:

```
df$H <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
  x + df$T[y] * (df$g[y] == df$g[y + 1]) * (df$S[y] - x) 
}, init = 0,
seq_len(nrow(df))[-nrow(df)], accumulate = TRUE)

df

           S         T g        H
1  37.698250 0.8550377 a  0.00000
2   3.843585 0.4722659 a 32.23342
3  33.150788 0.3684791 a 18.82587
4   8.948116 0.8893603 a 24.10430
5  57.061844 0.5452377 a 10.62499
6  49.648827 0.7719067 b 10.62499
7  95.403697 0.5835950 b 40.74775
8  10.598677 0.1220491 b 72.64469
9  91.913365 0.2166443 b 65.07203
10 69.644200 0.2603413 b 70.88705
```

Comment: So you want to remov the intermediate here

Comment: Yes just bind_row the first and the last one without dff that's all.

Comment: You may need `~  {tmp <- ..1 + ..3 * (..2 - ..1); tmp[c(1, length(tmp))] }))`

Comment: Oh I have to put it in the `.f` for the second chunk?

Comment: If you are returning the 1st and last for the first accumulate2

Comment: I actually want to retain the last `H` for `g == "a"` which is `10.62499` and use it as the `.init` for the next one.

Comment: So, if I understand then `.init` should take only the value from the last iteration.  Then, your code is fine.

Comment: Yes exactly. The result is ok I was just trying to make it more streamlined.

Comment: Isn't this similar to the one Anil used which looks more compact

Comment: He used some unusual tricks lol, I just wanted to find another way to differentiate the answers.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(nr = rowid(g)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = g, values_from = c(S, T)) %>% mutate(H_a = unlist(accumulate2(S_a[-n()], T_a[-n()], .init = 0, ~  ..1 + ..3 * (..2 - ..1))), H_b = unlist(accumulate2(S_b[-n()], T_b[-n()], .init = last(H_a), ~  ..1 + ..3 * (..2 - ..1)))) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -nr, names_to = c(".value", "g"), names_sep="_") %>% arrange(g) %>% select(-nr)`

Comment: Aww thank you very much dear Arun, it is fantastic. I will add it and use it to modify mine. Why don't you just post it so that the OP has 3 options.

Comment: @akrun Finally modified mine! :)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help with this, it is really appreciated. I would like to accept akrun's answer because it is the generalised version. I realise I had not explicitly said this in the question.